# Using jQuery to check if email is valid form ModelForm

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-templates

Hi I have a model form which is done based on the documentation found:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

Some attributes of my feedback form:

Models.py

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    feedback = models.TextField()
```

class FeedbackForms(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Feedback

forms_details.py

```
def save_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FeedbackForms(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            feedback = form.cleaned_data['feedback']

            email = EmailMessage("%s" % title, "%s <%s> said: %s" % (name, email,feedback),
                                 to=['smth@example.com'])
            email.send()
            return render_to_response("success.html")
    else:
        form = FeedbackForms()
    return render_to_response("form.html", {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

However, now I want to use jQuery to check if the email keyed in is valid before i do the POST.

I found something similar to what I need [here](https://github.com/alex/django-ajax-validation/blob/master/docs/usage.txt) but it's for forms. I've tried it but it didn't work for my ModelForm.

Answer (score 0):

There are client-side form validation plugins for jQuery to be sure, but you really don't need to use one. You can do all of your validation server-side via Ajax and return form errors as JSON before you attempt to persist any data. This way you don't have to maintain two sets of validation, and you get the same result.

[Shameless self-plug] I wrote some [base form classes](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2393/) that do exactly that via jQuery that you can use on Django Snippets.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isEmail(email)) {
//Do something
}

function isEmail(emailaddress) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(emailaddress);
}
```